# Ideals in the localization $R_p$

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and let $p$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.
The localization of $R$ at $p$, $R_p$, is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $pR_p$.

Now let $I$ be an arbitrary (= not necessarily prime) ideal of $R$ such that $I \subseteq p$.

Assume that $IR_p=pR_P$.

> **Question:** Is it true that $I=p$?

Of course, if we knew that $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then by the known result
concerning the one-one correspondence between prime ideals of $R_p$ and prime ideals of $R$ contained in $p$, we would have obtained that $I=M$.
However, here $I$ is not known to be a prime ideal of $R$.

Relevant questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77280/preservation-of-ideals-in-localized-rings), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588088/prime-ideals-of-a-localization#:%7E:text=There%20exists%20a%20bijection%20between,if%20n%E2%88%89(p).), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280885/bijection-between-prime-ideals-of-r-p-and-prime-ideals-of-r-contained-in-p?rq=1); the second answer in reference 3 quotes Theore 5.32 from "Steps in commutative agebra" by Sharp,
and it seems that I need some version of Theorem 5.30, just without the primality assumption (still with contraction and extension of ideals).

**Remark:**
$R=\mathbb{Z}$, $p=0$ is not a counterexample.

**Edit:** What if $R$ is an integral domain?

Thank you very much!

**Edit 2:** Now asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093536/a-sandwich-theorem-for-local-rings/4093553#4093553) more general question.

Comment: By $IR_p$ do you mean the ideal in $R_p$ generated by $I$?

Comment: @marlasca23, yes, exactly. Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430835/localization-at-mathfrak-p-extension-and-contraction-of-an-ideal

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank you very much for the counterexample! What if $R$ is an integral domain? Does this help?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: Obviously my gut was wrong about the integral domain case [see Atticus' answer]

Comment: @user237522 apologies, I deleted my answer briefly when I saw that you were asking for $\mathfrak{p}$ to be a *maximal* ideal. in my initial example $\mathfrak{p}$ was only prime, and not maximal. but this is easy to correct, and you can see a corrected example in my answer below :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, no need to apologize :) Thank you for the integral domain counterexample! Yes, I have seen your almost counterexample with $R=k[x,y]$ and $I=(xy) \subset (x)=p$, which is prime non-maximal. What about finding a counterexample in the two-dimensional ring  $R=k[x,y]$?

Comment: I do not mind to assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$, in order to apply Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, so $p=(x-a,y-b)$, $a,b \in k$.

Comment: (maybe I should have denoted the maximal ideal by $m$ not by $p$).

Comment: Oh, I see now that we can take $p=(x,y), I=(x(x-1),y)$...\

Comment: indeed, that works! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true, even if $R$ is an integral domain. Consider the case when $R$ is the polynomial ring $F[x]$ over your favorite field $F$, and let $\mathfrak{p}=\langle x\rangle$ and $I=\langle x(x-1)\rangle$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal and $I$ is a strict subset of $\mathfrak{p}$, but, in the localized ring $R_\mathfrak{p}$, the element $(x-1)\big/1$ is a unit, and we hence have $$I_{\mathfrak{p}}=\left\langle x(x-1)\big/1\right\rangle\ni \left(x(x-1)\big/1\right)\left(1\big/(x-1)\right)=x\big/1,$$ whence $I_\mathfrak{p}\supseteq\mathfrak{p}_{\mathfrak{p}}=\left\langle x\big/1\right\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  After I saw this it occurred to me that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ also provides a ton of counterexamples since its only nonzero ideals are $p^n\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! Please, are there interesting special cases where $I=p$ after all?

Comment: @BrianMoehring indeed! :) I'm very geometrically-minded so I like polynomial ring examples when possible, but perhaps an example from $\mathbb{Z}$ is even simpler!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but, for example, if $I=\langle \lambda a\rangle$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\langle a\rangle$ are both principal ideals, then we will have $I_{\mathfrak{p}}=\mathfrak{p}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ if and only if $\lambda\notin\mathfrak{p}$. (so, eg, the example above works because $\lambda=x-1\notin\mathfrak{p}$, and, as @BrianMoehring alludes to, you can whip up similar examples in $\mathbb{Z}$ like $I=\langle 6\rangle\subset\langle 2\rangle=\mathfrak{p}$.)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, interesting, thank you again.