# A sandwich theorem for local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, local-rings, regular-rings

The following question seems natural to ask in view of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092004/ideals-in-the-localization-r-p) question and its comments/answers:

Let $R \subseteq S$ be commutative Noetherian rings, let $q$ be a maximal ideal of $S$,
$p$ a maximal of $R$ and $p=R \cap q$.

The localization of $R$ at $p$, $R_p$, is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $pR_p$ and
the localization of $S$ at $q$, $S_q$, is a local ring with unique maximal ideal $qS_q$.

Since $p=R \cap q$, we can view $R_p$ as a subring of $S_q$.

Let $pS \subseteq I \subseteq q$ be an ideal of $S$ (not necessarily prime),
and then $I_q \subseteq S_q$ is an ideal of $S_q$ (where $I_q:=IS_q$).

Assume that $(pR_p)S_q = I_q = qS_q$,
where $(pR_p)S_q$ is the ideal of $S_q$ generated by $pR_p$ (this makes sense, since
$pR_p \subset R_p \subseteq S_q$).

> **Question:** Is it true that $I=q$?
>
> If not, would it help to further assume one or more of the
> following conditions:
>
> **(i)** $R \subseteq S$ is flat.
> **(ii)** $R \subseteq S$ is integral.
> **(iii)** $\dim(R)=\dim(S) < \infty$ ($\dim$ is Krull dimension).
> **(iv)** $R$ and $S$ are [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring#:%7E:text=In%20commutative%20algebra%2C%20a%20regular%20ring%20is%20a%20commutative%20Noetherian,equal%20to%20its%20Krull%20dimension.) rings.

**Remark:** The name 'sandwich' comes from the assumption
that $(pR_p)S_q = I_q = qS_q$; call it 'the sandwich equation'.

**A non-counterexample:** Without condition **(iii)**, the following is not a counterexample: $R=k[x]$, $S=k[x,y]$, $p=(x)$, $q=(x,y)$, $I=(x(x-1),y)$.
Indeed, the sandwich equation is not satisfied: only the right equality is satisfied, but not the left equality.

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $R$ is the ring of integers of a number field $K$, $p$ be a nonzero prime ideal, $S$ be the ring of the integers of $K(e^{2i\pi/r})$ where $r$ is a prime number coprime to $r$ with $r-1 > [K:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Let $q$ be any prime ideal of $S$ lying over $p$: then $K(e^{2i\pi/r})/K$ is unramified at $p$ thus $(pR_p)S_q=qS_q$. So if $I$ is any ideal of $S$ with $pS\subset I \subset q$, $I_q=qS_q$ too.

If the statement holds, then it follows (by characterization of prime ideals from Dedekind domains, else we can take eg $I=qq’$, where $q’$ is another prime ideal of $S$ lying over $p$) that $pS=q$, thus that $p$ is inert in $K(e^{2i\pi}/r)$, and this certainly isn’t systematic – the final part gives an elementary example.

Now, assume $K=\mathbb{Q}$: even in this setting where (i),(ii),(iii),(iv) all hold, $p$ is inert in $K(e^{2i\pi/r})$ iff $S/pS$ is an integral domain, iff $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2i\pi/r}]/(p)$ is a domain, iff $\mathbb{Z}[T]/(\Phi_r,p)$ is a domain, iff $\Phi_r$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$.

Now fix $r > 3$ and choose $p$ congruent to $1$ mod $r$, then $\Phi_r|X^r-1|X^{p-1}-1$ which is split with simple roots in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$, so that $\Phi_r$ cannot be irreducible and thus $p$ isn’t inert and we can find a “problematic” ideal $I$.

Comment: Thank you very much; very nice! Please, which of conditions (i)--(iv) is satisfied by your counterexample and which is not?

Comment: All the conditions are satisfied – it’s a ring of cyclotomic integers over $\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: Thank you very much, interesting. Please, could you find a counterexample in polynomial rings?

Comment: The following is not a counterexample, since the sandwich equation is not satisfied: $R=k[x^2,y^2]$, $S=k[x,y]$, $p=(x^2,y^2)$, $q=(x,y)$, $I=(x^2,y)$ or $I=(x,y^2)$.

Comment: If I am not wrong, $k[x^2,y^2] \subset k[x,y]$ is not flat.

Comment: To generate any number of counter-examples, remember that if $R$ is a Dedekind ring of fraction field $K$ and $S$ is the integral closure of $R$ in a finite separable extension $L$ of $K$, then conditions (i)-(iv) all hold. The squeeze equation holds for any $I$ if $L/K$ is unramified at $q/p$, but the conclusion holds for $p$ and $q$ only if $p$ is inert. Cyclotomic $L/K$ are nice enough examples where you can actually understand easily which prime ideals are inert.

Comment: @user237522: $k[x^2,y^2] \subset k[x,y]$ is free of rank $4$, I think.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Are there special cases (regardless of conditions (i)-(iv)) where we can conclude that $I=q$?

Comment: Thanks, yes, of course it is free of rank $4$. I confused flatness with separability.. Please, is your counterexample separable? Sorry for asking so many questions..

Comment: Well, you still need $I=pS$ to yield $I=q$ so you need $pS$ to be prime, basically. That’s enough in my Dedekind ring setting (probably if $R \subset S$ integral injective too).

Comment: Please, did you claim that $I=pS$ implies (without conditions (i)-(iv)) that $I=q$?

Comment: I stated that if the conclusion held for $I=pS$, then $pS=q$. That’s just tautology.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Please, does it help to assume $I=pS$?