# Flat and algebraic (non-integral) local rings extension $R \subseteq S$ with $m_RS=m_S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, flatness, local-rings

Let $R \subseteq S$ be two Noetherian local rings (not necessarily regular) which are integral domains,
with $m_RS=m_S$, namely, the ideal in $S$ generated by $m_R$ (= the maximal ideal of $R$) is $m_S$ (= the maximal ideal of $S$).

Further assume that $R$ and $S$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, $R \subseteq S$ is *flat* and *algebraic* but not integral (algebraic non-integral means: Every element of $S$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients in $R$, with non-invertible leading coefficient).

> Could one find an example of such rings?

Unfortunately, the examples I find are integral, for example:
$R=\mathbb{C}[x(x-1)]_{(x(x-1))}$, $S=\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$.

**Remarks:**

**(i)** I am interested in both cases where $R$ and $S$ have the same fields of fractions or different fields of fractions.

**(ii)** Recall the following results, which are not applicable here, since I assume that $R \subseteq S$ is non-integral:
If $A \subseteq B$ is integral and flat, then $A \subseteq B$ is faithfully flat, and if in addition, $Q(A)=Q(B)$ (same fields of fractions), then $A=B$.

Relevant questions: [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093536/a-sandwich-theorem-for-local-rings/4093553?noredirect=1#comment8461064_4093553), [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092004/ideals-in-the-localization-r-p?noredirect=1#comment8457172_4092004) and [c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092716/definition-of-homomorphism-of-local-rings/4093922#4093922). Also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390132/local-rings-r-subseteq-s-with-m-rs-m-s), and quite immediately got an answer there; **however**, it seems that the answer there does not describe the special case $S=R[w]$, for some $w \in S$
(which I mentioned there in a comment after the answer).

Any hints and comments are welcome; thank you.

Comment: [Asking the same question on MSE and MO in such a short time period is generally frowned upon](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo/16290#16290). You should probably also find some way to communicate that this question was answered at MO, and that you accepted the answer there.

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for your comment. The link is relevant and informative. Ok, you are right, from now on if I will ask the same question both on MSE and MO and get a good answer in one of them, I will inform the other. (I now edited the above question: "... and quite immediately got an answer there").